# How to add polymorphic address to devise custom registration controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to setup a custom registration controller using Devise and a polymorphic address model, but can't seem to actually get the address to save to the database.

Here is my controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  def new
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_address
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  private
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) {|u|
     u.permit(:first_name,:last_name,:mobile,:landline,:email,:password,:password_confirmation, :current_password, address_attributes: [:line_1,:line_2,:city,:region,:post_code,:country])
     }
  end
end
```

my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :address, through: :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  ... (other attributes)
```

my address model:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

relevant part of routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations'}
devise_scope :user do
  get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  get '/signup', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
end
```

and finally the relevant part of the view  view:

```html
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= devise_error_messages! %>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :last_name %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %>
          </div>


          <%= fields_for :address do |ff| %>

              <div class="field">
                <%= ff.label :line_1 %>
                <%= ff.text_field :line_1 %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= ff.label :line_2 %>
                <%= ff.text_field :line_2 %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= ff.label :city %>
                <%= ff.text_field :city%>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= ff.label :region%>
                <%= ff.text_field :region%>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= ff.label :post_code%>
                <%= ff.text_field :post_code %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= ff.label :country %>
                <%= ff.text_field :country%>
              </div>
          <% end %>


          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :mobile %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :mobile, autofocus: true %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :landline %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :landline, autofocus: true %>
          </div>


          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %><br/>
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
            <% end %><br/>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-default" %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)